# How to update Ruby in Google SketchUp?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, sketchup, ruby-1.8

Currently Google SketchUp for Mac has Ruby version `1.8.5` which I find a bit outdated. I can update Ruby to 1.8.7 (OSX's version) by the following commands

```
$ cd /Applications/Google\ SketchUp\ 7/SketchUp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current
$ ls
Headers/       Resources/     Ruby
$ ls Headers/
config.h  defines.h intern.h  missing.h ruby.h

$ rm -r Headers
$ ln -s  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Headers
$ ln -fs /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Ruby
```

SketchUp starts without a problem and Ruby console shows version 1.8.7.

### 1.9.2

Now I try to go further and update to `1.9.2-rc2`. Google SketchUp requires `i386` binary, which can be produced by the following commands

```
$ cd ~/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/
$ ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386"  CFLAGS="-arch i386" LDFLAGS="-arch i386" ./configure  --with-arch=i386
$ make && sudo make install
```

Then I copy the necessary files to SketchUp:

```
$ cd /Applications/Google\ SketchUp\ 7/SketchUp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/
$ rm Headers Ruby

$ cp /usr/local/bin/ruby Ruby
$ mkdir Headers
$ cp /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-darwin10.4.0/ruby/config.h Headers/
$ cp /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h Headers/
$ cp -r /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/* Headers/
$ ls Headers
backward/   defines.h   dl.h        intern.h    missing.h   re.h        ruby.h      util.h      vm.h
config.h    digest.h    encoding.h  io.h        oniguruma.h regex.h     st.h        version.h
```

and when I try to start SketchUp I get the following error report

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/A/Ruby
  Referenced from: /Applications/Google SketchUp 7/SketchUp.app/Contents/MacOS/SketchUp
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Google SketchUp 7/SketchUp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/A/Ruby: can't map
    /Applications/Google SketchUp 7/SketchUp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/A/Ruby: can't map
    /usr/local/lib/Ruby: not a file
    /usr/lib/Ruby: not a file

Model: MacBookPro7,1, BootROM MBP71.0039.B05, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.62f5
```

Could you tell me why?

#### UPDATE1

[Dan Rathbun](http://groups.google.com/group/sketchupruby/browse_thread/thread/fc4278c7a2011582/a4e51c7970f165fa?hl=en&#a4e51c7970f165fa) made some tests and found the following

> On Win32 when I tried to get Sketchup
> to load any 1.9.x I got an "Entry
> point not found" for the ruby C
> function "rb_set_kcode" which is no
> longer in 1.9.x (it was renamed, and
> the Ruby people did not alias the old
> name to the new name.)
>
> Basically Sketchup calls rb_set_kcode
> to set the character encoding to UTF8
> just after loading the Ruby
> interpreter. It works fine for any
> Ruby in the 1.8.x branch, but in 1.9.x
> the Ruby project totally reengineered
> the character encoding, and gave all
> the C functions new identifiers, and
> added alot more functions.
>
> The solution for 1.9.x and Sketchup
> seems to be that Sketchup needs to be
> "Ruby Version Agile", which means a
> coding change by the Google Guys in
> Boulder.

Answer (score 1):

The C level API has changed in 1.9.1. Notice that the paths to gems indicate the API compatibility: `.../1.8/...` for the 1.8 line and `.../1.9.1/...` for the 1.9.2 line.

This makes it very difficult to upgrade without recompiling.

You can `require "backports"`; this will get you the most of the new methods of 1.9.x, but not the new syntax or the string encoding.

Comment: If SketchUp needs just some minor changes in Ruby sources to run `1.9.x`, then recompiling is fine for me. However, I will probably not find it myself due to the lack of experience in C-programming. As a workaround, I am going to write a DSL in Ruby `1.8.7` to work with my `1.9.x` classes via intermediate ruby-files, being loaded in SketchUp. I really hope that it will finally be possible to run SketchUp with Ruby `1.9`, so that this unnecessary step will be skipped.